# Individual houses in OS Zoomstack using QGIS - splitting terraced homes

Tags: qgis-3

I am mapping the UK in QGIS using an OS zoomstack geopackage. I would like to look at the area and perimeter of properties in the UK but this is not possible with terrace and semidetached houses as there is no distinction of the number of properties are within that block. Does anyone know of a layer I can overlay to solve this? Is there a shapefile that could be added that will show each individual home?

Answer (score 1):

You would need Ordnance Survey MasterMap Topography Layer:

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/products/mastermap-topography

Which is a very expensive product, but provides split buildings.

OpenStreetMap may be split terraces in some locations but would be unreliable.